# Meteor Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName

Tags: node.js, meteor, server

My meteor app runs on a nodechef.com server.
nodechef assigns a subdomain to my app. e.g. myApp.nodechef.com

However I the actual domain I want to use is something like myApp.com that I bought from namecheap.com

I have successfully redirected myApp.com to point to myApp.nodechef.com

However when my Meteor App sends a verification email, it still uses myApp.nodechef.com as the main url and not myApp.com when I want it to use myApp.com.

I am aware that it is possible to manually set
Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = myApp.com

However that would mean when I am testing it on a Localhost I would need to then delete the manual assignment of Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName to myApp.com

I was wondering if there is a higher solution where Meteor can use the domain name I bought e.g. myApp.com 
and not the subdomain that nodechef.com assigns to my app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you setting up the APP_URL env variable?

Comment: Hi no I have not made any changes to APP_URL....

Comment: Try to set the APP_URL env var to yours example: https:// www.yourapp.com